# Yesod: Using Github API v3 Library for Haskell

Tags: haskell, github, monads, github-api, yesod

I'm working on a project that builds on the simple yesod template. I am new to functional programming, haskell and Yesod so it's probably something obvious to anyone with Yesod experience. At the moment I am trying to make github API calls using this [library](https://github.com/phadej/github). I am getting some type issues and I'm not even sure how to start approaching solving them.

You can find my handler [here](https://github.com/StarStuffSteve/CS7009/blob/master/yesod_simple/project/Handler/Home.hs).

```
   Handler/Home.hs:43:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘HandlerT
                                    App IO (Either a0 GitHub.User)’
                with actual type ‘GitHub.Request k0 GitHub.User’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      possibleUser <- GitHub.userInfoForR "mike-burns"
    In the expression:
      do { maid <- maybeAuthId;
           possibleUser <- GitHub.userInfoForR "mike-burns";
           result <- either (("Error: " <>) . tshow) formatUser possibleUser;
           defaultLayout
             (do { (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
                     ((blaze-markup-0.7.1.1:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                       GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                        "<p>Your current auth ID: ");
                   (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget) (toHtml (show maid));
                   (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
                     ((blaze-markup-0.7.1.1:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                       GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                        "</p>\n");
                   .... }) }


   Handler/Home.hs:44:38:
    Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘HandlerT App IO a1’
    Expected type: a0 -> HandlerT App IO a1
      Actual type: a0 -> Text
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘tshow’
    In the first argument of ‘either’, namely
      ‘(("Error: " <>) . tshow)’


   Handler/Home.hs:44:45:
    Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘HandlerT App IO a1’
    Expected type: GitHub.User -> HandlerT App IO a1
      Actual type: GitHub.User -> Text
    In the second argument of ‘either’, namely ‘formatUser’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      result <- either (("Error: " <>) . tshow) formatUser possibleUser
```

Comment: Instead of `possibleUser <- GitHub.userInfoForR "mike-burns"` write `let possibleUser = GitHub.userInfoForR "mike-burns"`

Comment: Hi arrowd. That does indeed get rid of errors relating to the "possibleUser" line but then using that variable in the next "result line causes the following error (perhaps I need to structure it with an 'in'?):    `Handler/Home.hs:49:59:`  
    `Couldn't match expected type ‘Either a0 GitHub.User’`   
                `with actual type ‘GitHub.Request k0 GitHub.User’`  
    `In the third argument of ‘either’, namely ‘possibleUser’`  
    `In the expression:`  
      `either (("Error: " <>) . tshow) formatUser possibleUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub library seems to be about building requests, and running them. The `userInfoForR` does such a thing :

```
userInfoForR :: Name User -> Request k User
```

Once you have a request, you can run it with one of the following functions, depending if you need to authenticate or not:

```
executeRequest :: Auth -> Request k a -> IO (Either Error a)
executeRequest' :: Request RO a -> IO (Either Error a)
```

I don't know about this specific case, but let's say you don't need authentication. So, the following expression would do the trick:

```
executeRequest' (userInfoForR "mike-burns") :: IO (Either Error User)
```

Now, in order to use it in a `Handler`, you'll need to learn about the fact that `Handler` is an instance of `MonadIO`, and you can thus do:

```
euser <- liftIO (executeRequest' (userInfoForR "mike-burns"))
case euser of
    Left rr -> ...
    Right user -> ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm still not quite there. Although I think I understand the problem a bit more.  I pushed some new code with your suggestions [link](https://github.com/StarStuffSteve/CS7009/blob/master/yesod_simple/project/Handler/Home.hs).  I am getting the following error `Handler/Home.hs:26:18: Parse error in pattern: GitHub.userInfoForR`    What are we trying to pattern match here?    Again, my apologie for my general ignorance in this area.

Comment: What's on the left of the equal sign is pattern matched. You can't call a function there.

Comment: Is the second executeRequest' type declaration you write meant to be the body of the function or is a body of the function not required?

Comment: Turns out I was trying to use some pretty out of date sample code. The executeRequest approach you mentioned works fine.